# Does it make sense? "Fix wrong globally installed applications privileges"

Tags: meaning, grammar

Does this sentence:

> Fix wrong globally installed applications privileges

is grammatically (and semantically) correct?

Comment: Incidentally, "does this sentence is grammatically correct" does not is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

> *Fix wrong globally installed applications privileges*

No, this sentence is unclear and ungrammatical on several points.

First, it should be **application privileges** (not *applications privileges*). Second, it's unclear whether you are referring to globally installed applications, or globally messed-up privileges.

Depending on what you mean, try:

> Fix incorrect privileges for the globally installed applications

Or:

> Fix incorrect global privileges for the installed applications